# ASP.NET MVC - One Business Service Needs to Call Another Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a RefData Service (Business Service) which loads all referance data from DB and caches in memory (Custom Cache Server). Many of my controllers call this service whenever they need this data.

I also have a Pricing Service (Business Service) which connects to external WebService to get Product pricing, once it gets all prices it has to get some content data from DB and merge with pricing response before it hands over final response to controllers. Now most of this data routines are already exposed by the RefData service. I don't want to write duplicate methods in my Pricing Service to get same data which is exposed and cached by Ref Data Service. Also I cannot move these routines into Pricing Service because my controllers also need this data and it does not belong in Pricing Service...

I am kind of in a situation where my Pricing service needs to call RefData service to get some data before it can hand over the response to Controllers. I couldn't find any write ups or samples where One Business Service calls another Service.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 and Unity as my IOC. I would appreciate your suggestions of what approach should I take.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of my app I register all my services with my IOC container. When one needs to call another, I simply resolve the one I need and call it.

Perhaps I am missing something about your qestion?

In Global.asax.cs:

```
        var authorizationRepository = new AuthorizationRepository(session);
        IoC.Container.RegisterInstance<IAuthorizationRepository>(authorizationRepository);
        var permissionBuilderService = new PermissionsBuilderService(session, authorizationRepository);
        IoC.Container.RegisterInstance<IPermissionsBuilderService>(permissionBuilderService);
```

When I need a service:

```
        var repository = IoC.Container.Resolve<IAuthorizationRepository>();
        repository.DoSomething();
```

Comment: rboarman, I know I can do that. What I meant to ask was it is advisable to call One Service from another as I didn't see this being suggested anywhere or is there a better way to handle such scenario? I am sorry if I didn't put it rigght in my question...

Comment: It's very common and pretty much required by any system of any complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common for one service to need another service. One example would be an authorization service. If you find a service is required in **all** other services, maybe it's time to make a base service that you can inherit from?